# How to lower bound the value 6.15 to 6.1 in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How to round off the below values in SQL?

35.38
53.08
6.15
5.38

to

35.4
53.1
6.1
5.4

Comment: use decimal data type  length for 2,1

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT CAST(FLOOR(6.15 * 10) / 10 AS NUMERIC(8,1))
```